# I have a netgear gs716tp managed switch, which drops offline regularly. I Unplug it from LAN and plug it in fixes it. Do I need a new switch?

Tags: networking, switch

It's a very weird issue.  I have my managed switch - a GS716TP, which every day or so now completely drops off my network, along with everything that is plugged into it.

If I unplug the cable from my main router that goes to the managed switch, and plug it back in immediately, then the switch comes back online after a few seconds, and everything is fine for a day or so.  It's not dropping off at a regular time, but approximately every day lately (it has gotten much worse recently.  It previously had only happened a few times).

I'm guessing this is some kind of weird hardware problem, and unplugging / plugging it back in is forcing the switch to re-initialize something that has gotten messed up, but I'm open to any suggestions.

One other thing that is a bit weird too all the other devices plugged into the switch can still communicate with each other. It's just the other part of the lan that is connecting through the one port that is gone. It's like just that port is bad maybe.  I have a spare port so I am going to try swapping the cable to a different port.  I will update this if that fixes the problem.

UPDATE (2 weeks later):
I didn't do a full reset, but I did update the firmware, and I haven't had the issue since -- the firmware hadn't been updated in awhile.

Comment: Have you tried a full hardware reset to initial settings, and then see if you can upgrade the firmware in the switch.  If this does not work, replacement is likely the next step.

Comment: that's a good idea -- I haven't done that because there is a fair bit of configuration I will need to do to get it back to working, but it makes sense to try, thanks for the suggestion, I'll give that a try.